# What are the benefits of the V13 Android Support Library?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm searching for the benefits of `android.support.v13.app` and from the SDK it appears to benefit Fragments in someway.

Since I'm new to fragments in general, I'd like to learn if all fragments rely on this particular library, and what improvements have been made between V13 and the modern API.

I looked at the [training material here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), see that fragments were introduced in API 11, and am trying to understand the benefit of v13.

Can anyone explain the benefits of this library, and/or how it enables more flexibility in development?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to learn if all fragments rely on this particular library

No fragments rely upon that library.

> what improvements have been made between V13 and the modern API

There are no fragments in that library.

> Can anyone explain the benefits of this library

There are two "classic" Android Support libraries, known as `support-v4` and `support-v13`. If you hear of somebody referring to "the Android Support library", they mean `support-v4`. `support-v4` has lots and lots of things (all of the `android.support.v4.*` packages). Among those things are two items of relevance for this answer:

- `support-v4` has a backport of fragments, for apps supporting devices that are older than API Level 11
- `support-v4` has `ViewPager` — if you have seen apps with "page at a time" horizontal swipe support, odds are that is `ViewPager`

`ViewPager` uses a `PagerAdapter` to supply the pages. Two concrete `PagerAdapter` implementations ship with `support-v4`: `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Since this is `support-v4`, those classes use the backported fragments (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`) for their pages.

Historically, `support-v13` had just implementations of `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that support the native, API Level 11 implementation of fragments (`android.app.Fragment`).

More recently, `support-v13` added:

- An implementation of `FragmentTabHost` that uses fragments for the contents of the tabs
- `FragmentCompat`, which, like most `...Compat` classes in Android, provide some `static` helper methods to make it easier for you to use APIs akin to the latest-and-greatest version of Android, with graceful degradation to older versions of Android

Of note, the `support-v13` `FragmentCompat` provides static methods to help you use the new Android 6.0 runtime permissions system with the API Level 11 edition of fragments.

Comment: So why use support-v4 then and not support-v13?

Comment: @JudeFernandes: If you are using the backport of fragments, `support-v13` gives you no added value.